# How to make a label show on a specific time in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I'm making an iOS application for iPhone, and I want to have two labels that is hidden on a specific time and shown on a specific time. Like Label1 is shown between 6am and 6pm and Label2 is shown between 6pm and 6am
Any ideas?

Comment: @ Joakim, you can use nstimer and set a fire time with nsdate. Set the time or the action that invokes the firing of the timer to show the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSDate date];` gives you the current date .Use date fromatter to get the fromat you need and use `setText:` method to set the text.Fire it in a timer and set the text

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[yourLabel setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
```

EDIT

full code,Try this

```
-(void)showtext
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
    if(  [self compareTimeIsbetween6])
    {
        [self.date1Label setHidden:NO];
        [self.date2Label setHidden:YES];
      [self.date1Label setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    }
    else
    {
        [self.date1Label setHidden:YES];
        [self.date2Label setHidden:NO];
        [self.date2Label setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    }
}

-(BOOL)compareTimeIsbetween6
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];
    NSInteger currentMinute = [components minute];
    NSInteger currentSecond = [components second];

    if (currentHour < 6 || (currentHour > 18 || (currentHour == 18 && (currentMinute > 0 || currentSecond > 0)))) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showtext) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *date1Label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *date2Label;
```

Comment: I'm a really newbie at Objective C. Would you please write the full code for if it should hide/unhide a label at a specific time? Maybe an if-statement?

Comment: @JoakimJojoElgsæther : Edited the answer ,Try it

Comment: Thanks! Now I've made a @property for the labels and then I tried to Build and Run the project, but it didn't work. What should I do, to make the code work?

Comment: did you connect the outlet

Comment: When i try to run it I get this error code:
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: Oh. Of course. I changed the name after making the property, and forgot to  connect it again. So now it almost works, but now the label just shows me the time, and not the text...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];
```

Now you have the hour, just add your normal logic.
if want to be change the formate do this...

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
      // another is   [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"]; 
 NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:today]);
```

Comment: I'm a really newbie at Objective C. Would you please write the full code for if it should hide/unhide a label at a specific time? Maybe an if-statement?

Comment: if ( hour > 6 && hour < 18 ) {
  [label1 setHidden:YES];
  [label2 setHidden:NO];
} else {
  label1.hidden = NO;
  label2.hidden = YES;
}